# How to fix "no-param-reassign" eslint error?

Tags: javascript, eslint

How to fix error  `"no-param-reassign": [2, {"props": false}]"`

This is example where I am getting the Eslint error:

```
 filtersList.forEach((filter) => {
      if (filter.title === 'Timeframe') {
        filter.options.forEach((obj) => {
          obj.selected = false;
        });
      }
    });
```

How to fix this?

Comment: How is this function being used? Can you show where it's being invoked, and where its result is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're modifying your `filterList` in place with `forEach`, use `map` instead:

```
filtersList.map(filter => {
  if (filter.title === "Timeframe") {
    return {
      ...filter,
      options: filter.options.map(obj => ({ ...obj, selected: false }))
    };
  }
  return filter;
});
```

Comment: The final line should be - return {...filter} - otherwise map's returned array will end up referencing the original array. More on this here - https://dev.to/lofiandcode/can-map-mutate-the-original-array-yes-dmb

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code mutates objects in the parameter array, which is causing the linter error. Either disable the linter rule for the line, or create new objects instead of mutating, eg:

```
const changedFilters = filtersList.map((filter) => {
  if (filter.title !== 'Timeframe') {
    // you can clone the object here too, if you want
    return filter;
  }
  return {
    ...filter,
    options: filter.options.map((obj) => ({
      ...obj,
      selected: false
    }))
  };
});
```

Then use the `changedFilters` variable later on in the code. This ensures that nothing is mutated.